# Filling a python list by preallocating and `my_list[x] = y` as syntactic sugar for `__setitem__`.

Tags: python, optimization

In working on some optimizations for my code in Python 2.7, I stumbled upon the following phenomenon:

```
>>> from timeit import timeit
>>> def fill_by_appending():
...     my_list = []
...     for x in xrange(1000000):
...             my_list.append(x)
...     return my_list
...
>>> def fill_preallocated_1():
...     my_list = [0]*1000000
...     for x in xrange(1000000):
...             my_list[x] = x
...     return my_list
...
>>> def fill_preallocated_2():
...     my_list = [0]*1000000
...     for x in xrange(1000000):
...             my_list.__setitem__(x,x)
...     return my_list
...
>>> def fill_by_comprehension():
...     my_list = [x for x in xrange(1000000)]
...     return my_list
...
>>> assert fill_by_appending() == fill_preallocated_1() == fill_preallocated_2() == fill_by_comprehension()
>>> timeit("fill_by_appending()", setup="from __main__ import fill_by_appending", number=100)
5.877948999404907
>>> timeit("fill_preallocated_1()", setup="from __main__ import fill_preallocated_1", number=100)
3.964423894882202
>>> timeit("fill_preallocated_2()", setup="from __main__ import fill_preallocated_2", number=100)
12.38241720199585
>>> timeit("fill_by_comprehension()", setup="from __main__ import fill_by_comprehension", number=100)
2.742932081222534
```

It's no surprise to me that preallocating is faster than appending, or that comprehension is faster than anything else, but why is using `__setitem__` *three times slower* than using `[]`?

Initially, I had a theory that using `my_list[x] = x` either merely reassigned the reference stored in `my_list[x]` to the address of the new object, or maybe that the interpreter even noticed that both were of the same type and used an overloaded assignment operator, whereas a `setitem` call actually copied the memory over, BUT some experimenting proved me wrong:

```
>>> class MyList(list):
...     def __setitem__(self, x,y):
...             super(MyList, self).__setitem__(x,y**2)
...
>>> ml = MyList([1,2,3,4,5])
>>> ml[2]=10
>>> ml
[1, 2, 100, 4, 5]
```

Does someone know what's going on under the hood?

Comment: I'd guess `__setitem__` is a function call, when `[x] =` has a special meaning for the interpreter. Same reason why `[]` is faster than `list()` for creating new lists.

Comment: Side-note: For this specific case, the real answer is "just call `range(1000000)`" (or on Py3, `list(range(1000000))` if you really need a `list`), but I assume you're considering slightly more complicated fill patterns.

Comment: @ShadowRanger slightly :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generic method dispatch has extra overhead over syntax based dispatch; the latter [can directly call the C level equivalent of the `__setitem__` method](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2.7/Python/ceval.c#L1906), while the former must repeatedly look up and create a bound method, and dispatch the call through the generic method dispatch mechanism (more general == slower). Generic dispatch also means constructing a `tuple` of arguments to pass (where syntax based calls just read the values off the Python stack without constructing a `tuple`).

In addition, the Python level name is actually a thin wrapper, so calling `__setitem__` means one additional layer of calling before it reaches the C API, as it has to traverse one additional layer before it reaches `sq_ass_item` (the C layer slot that is the ultimate call that implements the assignment). [`METH_COEXIST` can be used to limit the slot wrapper overhead](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/structures.html#METH_COEXIST) according to the docs, but it looks like [that was only used for `__getitem__` on `list`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.6/Objects/listobject.c#L2371).

You can eliminate the method lookup and binding overhead by storing off the bound method, which might save a little work, but fundamentally, for CPython, syntax beats method calls; if the syntax is equally clear and not error prone, use syntax.  A prebinding example that might reduce some of the discrepancy would be:

```
def fill_preallocated_3():
    my_list = [0]*1000000
    set = my_list.__setitem__
    for x in xrange(1000000):
        set(x,x)
    return my_list
```

Comment: Thank you, and for the links to the CPython source especially! Do you know anything about why the choice to put `__setitem__` behind the extra layer was made? Does it have to do with inheritance?

Comment: @gmoss: No. They have a generic wrapper used for each of the defined C level slots; the C level slots take their arguments already parsed so that a C -> C call doesn't need to pack up arguments that will only be unpacked immediately; the wrappers provide the conversion layer from Python level generic calling conventions to slot specific call prototypes. It's all part of the cost of generic "varargs-like" function dispatch vs. specific C level function prototypes.

Comment: For the record, the reason not to do `METH_COEXIST` all the time is that it's not commonly needed (`__setitem__` isn't called directly often; it's usually bypassed to go straight for the C level slot through the syntax dispatch path), and the only way to make it meaningfully faster than the wrapper that parses and passes along to the C slot is to reproduce most of the code of the C level function in the coexisting Python exposed function (basically, copy pasting a ton of code). Not worth the maintenance hassle for a fairly minor gain.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra property lookup + a function call in the second function:

`def fill_preallocated_1():`

```
         ...
         32 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
         35 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_list)
         38 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
         41 STORE_SUBSCR         
         ...
```

`def fill_preallocated_2():`

```
         ...
         32 LOAD_FAST                0 (my_list)
         35 LOAD_ATTR                1 (__setitem__)
         38 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
         41 LOAD_FAST                1 (x)
         44 CALL_FUNCTION            2
         ...
```

Comment: Note: The property lookup cost is likely a fraction of the overhead of the generic `CALL_FUNCTION` vs. the specific `STORE_SUBSCR`. [My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44191990/364696) includes a variant test that would eliminate the property lookup expense to help isolate the components of the slowdown.

Comment: The function call is the main culprit - caching the `__setitem__` property gives an improvement of around 30% on my system. Not something to throw away, but optimized list assignment is more than three times faster. btw. on my system, same tests:  `fill_preallocated_1: 4.73s; fill_preallocated_2: 13.41s; fill_preallocated_3: 10.8s`

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation!